# Question about the meaning of " reserved " in this piece of news

Tags: word-meaning

Chhattisgarh has seen some of the worst violence. Polling began in part of the state on 10 April and continues with two further rounds in the coming weeks.Elsewhere, voting resumed in the fourth stage of the general election on Saturday in four states - Goa, Assam, Tripura and Sikkim.Sikkim, a tiny Himalayan state, is also holding local elections, including the contest for a seat in the regional assembly which is **reserved** for a Buddhist monk.
http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-india-27001888
My perception: ... which would belong to a male member of Buddhist. And all contestants in the small Himalayan state are male members of Buddhist.

- A million thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the word reserved is used an adjective and means "is kept specially for a particular purpose or person." The writer is saying that the seat is going to only be given to a Buddhist monk.

"Reserved seating" is a common phrase for seats that are meant for specific people. This could mean for a group of people, like Buddhists. An example of this is "press seating" for journalists reviewing an event or performance. It can also mean seating for a person or group that made reservations prior to an event.

Answer (score 0):

> *...a tiny Himalayan state, is also holding local elections, including the contest for a seat in the regional assembly which is reserved for a Buddhist monk.*

Certain states in India (especially eastern states of the nation) are under influence of Buddhism and there, the importance of this religion is more than other religions in the sense that majority of the people in that state believe that religion. Sikkim is one of them. In Sikkim Legislative Assembly, one seat is reserved for them. The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sikkim_Legislative_Assembly) on this makes it clear.

> The Sikkim Legislative Assembly is the unicameral state legislature of Sikkim state in north-eastern India. The seat of the Legislative Assembly is at Gangtok, the capital of the state. As of 2012, the assembly has been constituted six times. The strength of the house is 32.out of 32 seats 12 seats are reserved for schedule tribe which consists of the ethnic tribes i.e. bhutia, lepcha, sherpa and yonzon communities as specified during the merger of the kingdom of sikkim (monarchy) into India making it the 22nd state of the Indian republic in 1975, setting up a democracy within the state. **One seat in the house is reserved for a member from the Sangh i.e. a representation by a monk** who is nominated by the sangh which cromrise of all monks from all monasteries in Sikkim

Now...

> My perception: ... which would belong to a male member, **the Buddhist** - correct. 
>   And **all contestants** in the small Himalayan state are male members of Buddhist - not necessary but yes, **that monk** will represent all.